# How to initialize a struct in C#

Tags: c#, struct, initialization

I have some code to initialize a struct in C#:

```
namespace Practice
{
    public struct Point
    {
        public int _x;
        public int _y;

        public int X
        {
            get { return _x; }
            set { _x = value; }
        }

        public int Y
        {
            get { return _y; }
            set { _y = value; }
        }

        public Point(int x, int y)
        {
            _x = x;
            _y = y;
        }    
    }    

    class Practice
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Point p1;
            p1.X = 1;
            p1.Y = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

The above code gives a compiler error:

> error CS0165: Use of unassigned local
>   variable 'p1'

Why is this error being thrown?

Comment: This is actually one of my pet peeves in C#. Any local variable should be initialized to `default` IMO.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can't use a *property* in a struct until it knows all the *fields* have been filled in.

For example, in your case this should compile:

```
Point p1;
p1._x = 1;
p1._y = 2;
int x = p1.X; // This is okay, now the fields have been assigned
```

Note how you *don't* have to explicitly call a constructor here... although in well-encapsulated structs you almost always *would* have to. The only reason you can get away with this is because your fields are public. Ick.

However, I would strongly advise you *not* to use a mutable struct anyway. If you really want a struct, make it immutable and pass the values into the constructor:

```
public struct Point
{
    private readonly int x;
    public int X { get { return x; } }

    private readonly int y;
    public int Y { get { return y; } }

    public Point(int x, int y)
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}

...

Point p1 = new Point(1, 2);
```

Comment: I think you mean make it immutable.

Comment: @JonSkeet If I want the `struct` properties to be 'mutable', does that means I shouldn't use `struct`? I.e, what if I want to set new values to X and Y throughout the process?

Comment: @Roylee: Well *I* don't like mutable structs - others disagree. But the details of whether or not it should be a struct will depend on the context.

Comment: Is it still the proper approach with .NET 8 (2024)?

Comment: @Sandburg: Well, it's still valid - but you could use read-only autoprops these days. Or a record struct...

Answer (score 6):

You need to create a `Point` first and assign it to `p1`:

```
public static void Main()
{
  Point p1 = new Point();
  p1.X = 1;
  p1.Y = 2;
}
```

By the way, you can have a [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288208.aspx) on your struct - could make things easier:

```
//in Point.cs
public point (int x, int y)
{
   _x = x;
   _y = y;
}

//in program.cs
public static void Main()
{
  Point p1 = new Point(1, 2);
}
```

This also allows you to avoid having *setters* on a struct (keeping it immutable).

Answer (score 5):

You have to initialize it with `Point p1 = new Point();`

Comment: No you don't. See my answer for an example which will compile and run without any use of `new`.

Comment: You are absolutely correct. For a mutable struct, you actually don't need to use new, but mutable structs are evil anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

The statment: "Point p1;" requires a default constructor.
The default constructor will not be automatically prodived because of the
public Point(int x, int y) .
You need to provide a default constructor:
public Point() { ... }

Comment: Default constructors are not allowed on structs.