# Why is there no "Use of unassigned local variable" compile error on an empty user defined struct?

Tags: c#

The following compiles successfully:

```
struct Foo {}

void Test()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.ToString();
}
```

Whereas the following yields a "Use of unassigned local variable" compile error.

```
struct Foo
{
    int i;
}

void Test()
{
    Foo foo;
    foo.ToString();
}
```

It appears that in the first case, the compiler has made some sort of inference that since the struct has no members, they do not need to be initialized. But I'm not sure that this makes sense to me. The compiler could have forced you to initialize the `foo` variable as `new Foo()`.

So, if in C# all local variables must be initialized before accessing, *why does the first example compile*?

Comment: `A local variable must be definitely assigned (Section 5.3) at each location where its value is obtained`

Comment: You might have expected an answer from this man here on this very subject: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3943162/1073107 :-)

Comment: @dash: Yeah, sorry about the delay - was busy working :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Section 5.3 of the C# 5 specification covers this:

> A *struct-type* variable is considered definitely assigned if each of its instance variables is considered definitely assigned.

That's automatically the case when there are no instance variables, hence the variable is considered to be definitely assigned, and can be used in the `ToString()` call.

Comment: Ahhh I suppose the definition of `definite assignment` covers it :) Reading the code, however, I wouldn't have considered `foo` to be assigned as its constructor had not yet been called.

Comment: @ZaidMasud: You don't have to call a constructor for structs - if the fields are accessible, you could assigned them explicitly without calling `new(...)` and it would still be definitely assigned. Think of a value type variable as being a collection of sub-variables, in some sense.